# .htaccess rewrite forward to different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to forward these .htaccess rewrite rules to a different domain name?

```
RewriteRule ^Aff-Link/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?AffId=$1&ABanId=$2&ref_type=BA
RewriteRule ^AffConOpe-Link/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?AffId=$1&iACGId=$2&iOperatorId=$3&ref_type=CGO
RewriteRule ^AffStoPro-Link/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?AffId=$1&iAOSPGId=$2&iOSProductId=$3&ref_type=SPL 
RewriteRule ^AffStoProBuy-Link/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?AffId=$1&iAOSPGId=$2&iOSProductId=$3&ref_type=SPBL
RewriteRule ^AffLandLink/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?AffId=$1&iALPId=$2&ref_type=CLP
RewriteRule ^AffShowcase-Link/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) index.php?AffId=$1&iOperatorId=$2&ref_type=SCO
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well yes, you could send them by email for example.

Comment: Seriously: you can specify a full URL as target, not only a script name. For example: `RewriteRule ^Aff-Link/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) https://example.org/index.php?AffId=$1&ABanId=$2&ref_type=BA`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work fine for what I need.